# Translating SQL group-by query to LINQ query

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, group-by

I'm having troubles with trying to translate an SQL query to LINQ.
Suppose, we have the following data structure:

```
class Movie
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    // navigation properties
    public virtual ICollection<Commercial> Commercials { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Spectator> Spectators { get; set; }
}

class Commercial
{
    public Guid ID  { get; set; }
    public Guid MovieID { get; set; }
    public string ProductType { get; set; }

    // navigation property
    public virtual Movie Movie { get; set; }
}

class Spectator
{
    public Guid ID  { get; set; }
    public Guid MovieID { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    // navigation property
    public virtual Movie Movie { get; set; }
}
```

Now let's say, I want to find out, how many spectators saw a commercial for a certain product category. In SQL, it would look like this:

```
select Commercial.ProductType, count(distinct Spectator.ID)
from Spectator
join Movie on Spectator.MovieID = Movie.ID
join Commercial on Commercial.MovieID = Movie.ID
where Spectator.Age > 60 # optional filter
group by Commercial.ProductType;
```

First, I tried to use the `GroupBy()` function, but I didn't find a way to group the spectators by the commercial's product types due to the many-to-many relationship.

Then I tried something like:

```
var query = db.Commercials.Where(x => x.Age > 60).GroupJoin(
    db.Spectators,
    c => c.MovieID,
    s => s.MovieID,
    (c, g) => new { ProductType = c.ProductType, Count = g.Distinct().Count() });
```

This looked promising, but didn't return the expected results.

Comment: I am sorry. My first example was oversimplified and not even matching to the problem I actually have. I hope my new example contains all relevant informations needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have all these nice navigation properties, so you don't need to join in LINQ. A navigation property can be viewed as a hard-coded join, which prevents repetitive, verbose, and error-prone code (for example, using the wrong join properties).

Knowing this, you can think of the query to get your data. It's not as trivial as it seems (and as I first thought).

There can be `n` commercials in one movie, so if you simply count the spectators per movie and commercial the result is too high (`n` times the number of spectators). You have to count *unique* spectators. And these counts should be grouped by `ProductType`. That brings us to this query:

```
var query = from c in db.Commercials
            group c by c.ProductType into cgroup
            select new
            {
                ProductType = cgroup.Key,
                NumberOfSpectators = cgroup.SelectMany(c => c.Movie.Spectators
                     .Where(s => s.Age > 60)
                     .Select(s => s.Id)).Distinct()).Count()
            };
```

Comment: Wouldn't this create two results for two commercials of the same product type?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have relation between your database?
If yes your model that generated by entity framework must be like this:

```
 public class Receiver
    {
        public int LetterId { set; get; }
        public Letter Letter { set; get; }
        public Country Country { set; get; }
    }
    public class Letter
    {
        public int Id { set; get; }
        public int SenderId { set; get; }
        public Sender Sender { set; get; }
        public IEnumerable<Receiver> Receivers { set; get; }

    }
    public class Sender
    {
        public int Id { set; get; }
        public Country Country { set; get; }
        public IEnumerable<Letter> Letters { set; get; }
    }
    public class Country
    {
        public int Id { set; get; }
    }
```

then you have 3 types from your context:

```
IEnumerable<Receiver> receivers = new List<Receiver>();
IEnumerable<Letter> leters = new List<Letter>();
IEnumerable<Sender> senders = new List<Sender>();
```

so your response is like:

```
var results = from receiver in receivers
        from letter in leters
        from sender in senders
        where receiver.LetterId == letter.Id &&
              sender.Id == letter.SenderId
        select
            new Result
            {
                Country = sender.Country,
                CountOfCountry = sender.Letters.Select(x => x.Receivers).Distinct().Count()
            };
```

that ResultClass is :

```
public class Result
    {
        public Country Country { set; get; }
        public int CountOfCountry{ set; get; }
    }
```

If you put your class diagram I can help you better!

Comment: I'm sorry! I tried to simplify the problem, which I have, as much as possible. But I realized, that I oversimplified it. In my first example, a letter could have had more than one sender, which doesn't really make sense. I tried to find another, better fitting example. Thank you for your answer anyway!

Answer (score 0):

i have done small sample.

```
public class Letter
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SenderId { get; set; }
}
public class Sender
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
public class Receiver
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int LetterId { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
class StackOverflow_SQLtoLinq
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Letter> lstLetters = new List<Letter>() { 
        new Letter(){Id=1,SenderId=1},
        new Letter(){Id=2,SenderId=2},
        new Letter(){Id=3,SenderId=3}
        };

        List<Sender> lstSenders = new List<Sender>() {
        new Sender(){Id=1,Country="IND"}, 
        new Sender(){Id=2,Country="US"},  
        new Sender(){Id=3,Country="NZ"}
        };

        List<Receiver> lstReceivers = new List<Receiver>() { 
        new Receiver(){Id=1,LetterId=1,Country="IND"},
        new Receiver(){Id=2,LetterId=11,Country="US"},
        new Receiver(){Id=3,LetterId=1,Country="NZ"},
        };

        var data = (from receiver in lstReceivers
                   join letter in lstLetters on receiver.LetterId equals letter.Id 
                   join sender in lstSenders on letter.SenderId equals sender.Id
                    group sender by new { id = sender.Id, country = sender.Country } into finalData
                   select new
                   {
                       country = finalData.Key.country,
                       Count = finalData.Distinct().Count()
                   }).ToList();

    }
}
```

finally in have a data in **data** variable.

Comment: I'm sorry! I tried to simplify the problem, which I have, as much as possible. But I realized, that I oversimplified it. In my first example, a letter could have had more than one sender, which doesn't really make sense. I tried to find another, better fitting example. Thank you for your answer anyway!